# Reconnect method to chromecast from ios device

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast, google-cast

After learning normal google cast fundamentals, I am able to cast media to chromecast using Google chromecast SDK 3.2.0 however if my apps closes and when it comes back to foreground again, then I want my device to be auto connected to last connected device, so I stored the sessionid and device id however, I dont know which method to use to reconnect.

**Saving procedure**

```
    func didConnectToCastApplication
    applicationMetadata: GCKApplicationMetadata!,
                   sessionID: String!,
                   launchedApplication: Bool) {
    self.mediaControlChannel = GCKMediaControlChannel()
    mediaControlChannel!.delegate = self
    deviceManager.add(mediaControlChannel!)
    mediaControlChannel!.requestStatus()

    //storing sessionId  and deviceId into defaults
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(sessionID, forKey: "lastCCSessionId")
    if let deviceId = self.selectedDevice?.deviceID {
        defaults.set(deviceId, forKey: "lastCCDeviceId")
    }
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement [CastReceiverManager](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver#session-management) whereby the receiver application registers listener functions on the `onSenderConnected` and `onSenderDisconnected` properties.

The receiver manager allows communication with the platform and is used to to send/receive system messages/events. Do not instantiate this class directly; instead, obtain a reference to the singleton instance by calling getInstance(). By calling [`isConnected`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/cast.framework.RemotePlayer#isConnected) , if `True` the app is connected to a cast device.

For better understanding, you may read how to integrate Cast v3 into your IOS App: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_integrate